# How are you supposed to reallocate a sparse array?

Tags: c++, dictionary, sparse-matrix

With a trivially copyable class you can reallocate buffers with a simple memcopy. And with a container like a vector if the element type isn't trivially copyable then the solution would be to loop through all the members and move construct each element into the new buffer. However in the following case neither are possible, as far as I'm aware:

```
struct MyStruct
{
    MyStruct(){}
    MyStruct(MyStruct&& other) { a = other.a; }
    MyStruct& operator = (MyStruct& other) { a = other.a; }
    int a;
};

template <typename T>
struct SparseArray
{
    char* buffer = (char*) malloc(128);
    int capacity = 128 / sizeof(T);

    void createAtIdx(int idx) {
        if (idx >= capacity)
            // Then grow buffer. May need to move
            ;

        new (buffer[sizeof(T) * idx]) T;
    }
    void destroyAtIdx(int idx)
    {
        buffer[sizeof(T) * idx]->~T();
    }
};

int main()
{

    SparseArray<MyStruct> sparseArray;
    sparseArray.createAtIdx(3);
    sparseArray.createAtIdx(17);

    // Now lets say the buffer needs to grow / reallocate
}
```

What's the proper way to go about reallocating, or even destructor calls if shrinking the buffer? How are sparse arrays like this made? Are there any implementations out there of something like this? As far I know it's the fastest possible ['associative array', 'map', 'symbol table', or 'dictionary'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array) , but I'm having trouble with the concept of doing certain things with them, for example reallocating.

Comment: Use `std::vector` and a mapping from sparse index to representation index.

Comment: Why not using a [std::map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map)?

Comment: @molbdnilo Sorry, what do you mean? a std::vector<char> ? Edit: Oh, you mean add an extra layer or indirection, yeah that's a possibility. But I want to specifically know how to solve this. Edit: I also want to maximise performance for what i'm doing.

Comment: `buffer` here is just an array of pointers to where the actual data resides, so you should just be able to realloc it - data pointers will be copied to the new array and will not need to change.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Pretty sure you can't. I spent a while looking into this and asked a few questions about it. Because I've constructed a object of a type that's not trivially copyable memcpying it to another location is undefined as technically the object doesn't exist at the new location. Of course realistically a memcpy should work with any type, even a virtual one, (memcpy) copies the vtable pointer along with it. But technically it's undefined. The type is not not trivially copyable. I think really this is a technicality, but I guess with UB ...

Comment: ... the compiler is allowed to assume the object doesn't exist in the new location.